# Getting Realtime Reply From PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I have a really big php script that can be called from jquery using $.post or ajax. Now since this script is quiet long I have divided it into several parts, so what I want is when certain part of the script is complete I want to echo a flag and then on jquery should read that flag value and accordingly display a comment. So basically I want a loader that responds in real time.

For example lets say I have three segments in php, one that does validation and one that saves the data into the database and finally one that creates a file and keeps log in it. Now remember either all these segments should execute one after the other or none should occur hence it is a single call. So what I want to create is a loader that will notify the user when each segment finishes. Something like the following

```
<?php

/* code for segment one

......

*/

echo 1;

/* code for segment two

......

*/

echo 2;

/* code for segment three

......

*/

echo 3;

?>
```

Now most of you must have figured out that this script will ultimately produce an output as a string like '123' but I want each output sent one after the other. Is something like this possible? If yes please share an example.

Comment: Try removing `output_buffering` and check?

Comment: And here you have something about [**Streaming vs. Output Buffering**](https://www.sitepoint.com/php-streaming-output-buffering-explained/).

Comment: output_buffering did not work but you are right that link really helped me.

Comment: Would you like to explain what you did to solve, as I am also waiting for your answer on this. `:)`

Comment: Are you sure that you need to give feedback while processing? The size of a file is more a smell that you should use more classes, not that your program is to large. Also validating the data and putting it in the database should not take many ms so the full request should be back faster than the user can notice that a request is started

Comment: I need to clarify that I don't actually have a large file or a large program, its just a bulk upload thing (you know uploading a csv). The problem is the program has many individual loops so usually say you need to add products or employees using bulk upload (csv) then this program will take longer due to the size of the record being too high. Thats why I need to give the users a feedback that says yes the script is still running and right now its on this segment. Usual waiting time on my script is 10 to 20 minutes and the record size are on average 800-2500 records.

Answer (score 1):

In theory php scripts can return output to the client during execution, but in my experience this is unreliable, because the webserver might cache it.

I would rather break down your large php script into smaller parts and call each one separately. Each smaller php script can then return a message to the client signaling its progress. Context can be shared between the smaller php script by using the [session](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) feature.

Comment: Problem with session feature is that I will never know when the user is gone. For instance during my script if things go wrong at some segment I can delete the already entered records and undo thing but using session I cannot make sure what segment am I on or what went wrong, where and what changes I have to do to undo things, etc. Anyways Praveen Kumar's comment helped I am using ob_flush(); flush(); to solve my problem and giving feedback.

Comment: Frankly, I don't fully understand why you think using session would not work. Using session and controlling execution from the client should give you the very same abilities as if you do everything in one script.

Answer (score 1):

Php is synchronous so it executes codes line by line, and long action are blocking.

If you dont want to wait script response you can use diferent php files and diferent ajax call to simulate asynchronous execution.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'yourfile1.php',
    method: 'post',
    data: {

    }
}).done(function(response){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'yourScript2.php',
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            toPost: response
        }
    }).done(function(response2){
        // Ajax finished
    });
});
```

If you want real server asynchronous execution you can use nodejs on server side, witch has been created for that.

"Node.js uses an event-driven, non-blocking I/O model that makes it lightweight and efficient. "

https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: Although it is pretty interesting it is not for me since I will have to create and distribute my segments in different script and I don't want that.